# Flushing the Parse cache of all objects on user log out

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm currently using `PFUser.logout` to log out the user but am having an issue where when another user logs back in, they're able to see other object data such as their Listings or Settings still stored in the cache from the last user's session.

What's the best way to purge all local data so the next user can have a fresh experience?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the local store, or pins?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pins?

Comment: Pins are a way to cache Parse objects

Comment: Oh. There are no mentions of pins in my project so I imagine I'm not using pins